# Normalising a table structure for a very simple payments system

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am programming a very simple payments web app which is my first attempt at programming anything. I've run into trouble with my database structure, with people saying it should be normalized.

At the moment I have the following structure.

```
Customers
---------
id, firstName, lastName, country

Items
---------
id, itemName, itemCost

Purchases
----------
customerID, dayCost, serviceCost, numItem1, numItem2, numItem3

Orders
----------
orderId, customerId, amountPaid, date
```

I need to be able to do a query where I can display the following:

- Total : 140
- Day Cost: 50
- Service Cost: 70
- Coronas Cost: 20 (4)
- Item 2 Cost: 0
- Item  3 Cost: 0
- Total Owing: 100

My idea was to calculate, for example, ( purchases.numItem1 by item.itemName where id =  1 + purchases.dayCost + purchases.serviceCost ) - orders.amountPaid.

This isn't right and I'm not sure what it should be.

I need to be able to return in a query how much of each item the customer has ordered, the total cost for each item, and the total cost owing.

What is a better, normalized table structure to allow for this query?

I can't simply have an orders table with customer and item id and quantity and amount paid, because I have to work with a form on a webpage and that structure won't work.

Comment: Have you tried Data Flow Diagram or Relational Tables before? If not then I think its necessary to do that before.

Comment: What are daycost and servicecost?

Comment: @Olaf dayCost and serviceCost are arbitrary amounts, which will be entered directly via a text field form element on a page.

Comment: Is daycost and servicecost per item bought or is it per order?

Comment: @OlafDietsche Thanks for your help. dayCost and serviceCost are per customer, not per item. So a Customer might have 4 of 1 item and 2 of another item, so I need the total of that plus whatever value is in dayCost and serviceCost to get the total

Answer (score 0):

Customers and Items could be expanded when needed, but are fine so far.

If daycost and servicecost is per item, you could change purchases to

```
Purchases
----------
orderId, dayCost, serviceCost, itemid, itemsBought
```

Now you can calculate the cost of an order by

```
select sum(p.itemsBought * i.itemcost + p.daycost + p.servicecost) as itemsCost
from purchases p
join items i on p.itemid = i.id
where p.orderid = 17
```

or the amount a customer owes

```
select sum(p.itemsBought * i.itemcost + p.daycost + p.servicecost)
       - sum(o.amountPaid) as owing
from purchases p
join items i on p.itemid = i.id
join orders o on o.orderid = p.orderid
where o.customerid = 284
```